# how can I make select2 workable in vue js when i am adding select box dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, jquery-select2

```
<tr v-for="(tr, k) in trs">
    <td>
        <select v-model="tr.product_reference" id="products" class="form-control form-control-sm product_select2" style="width: 100%" required @change="get_imeis(k, tr.product_reference)">
            <option value="" selected>Select product...</option>
            <option v-for="(val, index) in products" :value="val.product_reference"> @{{val.product_name}} </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select v-model="tr.imei" id="imei" class="form-control form-control-sm imei_select2" style="width: 100%" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select IMEI...</option>
            <option v-for="(val, index) in tr.imeis" :key="index" :value="val.imei"> @{{val.imei}} </option>
        </select>
    </td>

</tr>

//VUE JS 
 mounted: function() {
      
         $(".product_select2").select2().on('change', function() {
             console.log(this)
             app.trs.product_reference = $(this).val();
         });
         $(".imei_select_2").select2().on('change', function() {
             app.trs.imei = $(this).val();
         });
    },
```

The first row is working but when I am creating new row, `select2()` is not working. I declared `select2()` in mounted when page loads. how can i enable `select2()` even after I added new row.
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use jquery inside vue?

Comment: **I highly recommend not using jquery in vuejs like this**. if you need **select2** you can use https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-select and when you define vue-select2 as a component there will be no problem when you want to create a new row.

Comment: @DavidGo i am using vuejs cdn, not vue cli

Comment: @AriShojaei Thank You, but i am using vuejs cdn in my php file....

Comment: @AriShojaei but the library you're referring to is using jQuery too. what's the difference?